# Chrome Application outerBounds are not being set correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background-process

I am trying to make a module that hangs out to the right of the screen. Here is my `background.js`

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  var users_screen_width = window.outerWidth, //these are both coming back as 0
      users_screen_height = window.outerHeight;
  chrome.app.window.create("index.html", {
    id: "testWindow",
    outerBounds:{
      width:40, //none of these bounds are being set correctly.
      height:250, //none of these bounds are being set correctly.
      left:1440, //none of these bounds are being set correctly.
      top:250 //none of these bounds are being set correctly.
    },
    frame:"none",
    resizable:false,
    alwaysOnTop:true
  },function(data){
     console.log(data); //this is below...
  });
});
```

**Logged Response**

```
outerBounds: 
   height: 300
   left: 540
   maxHeight: null
   maxWidth: null
   minHeight: null
   minWidth: null
   top: 280
   width: 458
```

Is there are minimum height and width requirements? If so I did not read this in any of the documentation http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html

So can someone tell me what is wrong here? Also how do I dynamically move the window with an eventListener??

Comment: add `px` to the numbers? e.g. `width:40px`

Comment: The values need to be integer so that will not work.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Has OP fixed this?

Comment: I don't remember I will look into my old Chrome Apps to see if I ever did fix this stupid problem and post the answer.

Comment: Is it possible Chrome is caching the window size, and those values are treated as a "suggestion" rather than forcing?